# Problem using postscript method with a scrolled frame

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I created a scolled frame by using the `ScrolledFrame` class written by @furas (which uses canvas).
I want to save the canvas created as an image. For this reason, I tried to use the postscript method of the canvas attribute of my scrolled frame, which is `sf._canvas` (where `sf=ScrolledFrame(tk.Tk())`). But I get the error: `TclError: invalid command name ".!scrolledframe.!canvas"`. The traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-7da2d37c56af>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Ing/Desktop/EN/stage/rapports/codes rev/test_affichage.py', wdir='C:/Users/Ing/Desktop/EN/stage/rapports/codes rev')

  File "C:\Users\Ing\Documents\anaaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Ing\Documents\anaaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Ing/Desktop/EN/stage/rapports/codes rev/test_affichage.py", line 111, in <module>
    ps=sf._canvas.postscript(file=input, colormode='color')

  File "C:\Users\Ing\Documents\anaaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2592, in postscript
    self._options(cnf, kw))

TclError: invalid command name ".!scrolledframe.!canvas"
```

The code used is:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os 
from PIL import Image

class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, vertical=True, horizontal=False):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # canvas for inner frame
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news') # changed

        # create right scrollbar and connect to canvas Y
        self._vertical_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self._canvas.yview)
        if vertical:
            self._vertical_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._vertical_bar.set)

        # create bottom scrollbar and connect to canvas X
        self._horizontal_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self._canvas.xview)
        if horizontal:
            self._horizontal_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        self._canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._horizontal_bar.set)

        # inner frame for widgets
        self.inner = tk.Frame(self._canvas)
        self._window = self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.inner, anchor='nw')

        # autoresize inner frame
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed

        # resize when configure changed
        self.inner.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)

        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        self.resize_width = False
        self.resize_height = False
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.inner_resize)

    def resize(self, event=None): 
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox('all'))

    def inner_resize(self, event):
        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        if self.resize_width:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, width=event.width)
        if self.resize_height:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, height=event.height)

dir_path=filedialog.askdirectory()
Input = ([[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6]]) 
color_1 = "#d1f3cd"
color_2 = "#b3ecac"
nb_color_shades=2
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sous-trame"+str(2))
sf = ScrolledFrame(root, True, True)
sf.pack(fill='both', expand=True) # resize with window

def get_max(my_list):
    m = None
    for i in my_list:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            i = get_max(i)
        if not m or m < i:
            m = i
    return m

def grid_function(tab):    
    rows = len(tab)
    cols = len(list(zip(*tab)))
    maximum = get_max(tab)
    range_color_1 = maximum/nb_color_shades

    for x in range(0, rows):
        for y in range(0, cols):
            current_element = tab[x][y]
            if current_element<=range_color_1:
                label=tk.Label (sf.inner, width="20", height="5", bg=color_1)
            elif current_element>range_color_1 :
                label=tk.Label (sf.inner, width="20", height="5", bg=color_2)
            label.grid (row=x,column=y)

grid_function(Input)

input="Sub-frame"+str(3)+".ps"
ps=sf._canvas.postscript(file=input, colormode='color')
img=Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8')))
#img=Image.open(ps)
img_name="Sub-frame"+str(2)+".bmp"
file_path=os.path.join(dir_path, img_name)
img.save(file_path, "BMP")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

By putting `root.mainloop()` inside `grid_function`, that function won't return until after the window has been destroyed. You then try to call a method on a widget, but that widget no longer exists. Whether you are using the ScrolledFrame class or some other class is irrelevant. The problem is that you are trying to access widgets after they have been destroyed.

You need to rearrange your code so that you call `self._canvas.postscript` before you destroy the main window rather than after.

Comment: I don't understand well. The function 'grid_function' returns None.  When I runned the instructions after "grid_function(Input)", I have not yet closed the window. So, what is the problem with 'root.mainloop()'?

Comment: I edited the code and put ' root.mainloop()' as the last instruction of the program. And now I get the following error:  " OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000023EB9EE50F8> "